# AngularJS: populate dropdown with json coming from mvc action

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

i have action in mvc which fire when page request and from there i generate the json of my model and store in viewbag. in razor view i store json from viewbag to angular model. my code suppose to populate dropdown but not getting right output. please tell me where i made the mistake.

### MVC Action

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Countries = GetCountries();
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetCountries()
        {
            List<Country> oList = new List<Country>()
           {
                new Country {ID=1,Name="United Kingdom"},
                new Country {ID=1,Name="United States"},
                new Country {ID=1,Name="Italy"},
                new Country {ID=1,Name="Germany"},
                new Country {ID=1,Name="India"}
           };
            return Json(oList);
        }
    }
```

### AngularJS code to populate dropdown

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-app="drpdwnApp" ng-controller="drpdwnCtrl">
        <select ng-model="ID" ng-options="item.Name for item in CountryList">
            <option value="" >--Select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


@section scripts
{
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('drpdwnApp', []).controller('drpdwnCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.CountryList = null;
        $scope.fillCountryList = function () {
            $scope.CountryList = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Countries))');
        };
        $scope.fillCountryList();
    });
</script>

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$http` service to make an ajax call to your server endpoint to get the data for your dropdown.

Since it is in an MVC view, you should take advantage of the `Url.Action` helper method to build the correct relative url to your endpoint. So in your view file, you may build the url to your endpoint and pass that to your javascript/angular controller.

```
@section Scripts
{
   <script src="~/Scripts/YourAngularControllerFileForThisPage.js"></script>
   <script>
        var yourApp = yourApp || {};
        yourApp.Settings = yourApp.Settings || {};
        yourApp.Settings.CountriesUrl= "@Url.Action("GetCountries","YourControllerName")";
        angular.module("app").value("appSettings", myApp);
   </script>
}
```

Now in your angular controller,

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope','$http', 'appSettings', function ($scope,$http,
                                                                             appSettings) 
{       
    $scope.CountryList = [];
    $http.post(appSettings.Settings.CountriesUrl).then(function(a) {
        $scope.CountryList = a.data; 
    });

}]);
```

While this works fine, ***I strongly recommend you to move this http call to a data service*** and inject that to your angular controller and use that.

Comment: in your code u said "You can use the $http service to make an ajax call to your server endpoint to get the data for your dropdown"  that i should call server side function by $http service to get country data but i populate viewbag with country data and in this way i can save one server hit by ajax. now tell me which one would be consider as good one ?

Comment: see your code `$http.post("Home/GetCountries")` u inject appSettings in controller but use hard code url during ajax call......did u forget to use appSettings or what was the objective behind appSettings or injecting in controller....not very clear.

Comment: Sorry ! Fixed it now. Sure, you can use viewbag too. But i prefer to not use dynamic stuff like view bag. This way my view is more clean.

Answer (score 0):

issue solved. here is the code which is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('drpdwnApp', []).controller('drpdwnCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.CountryList = null;
        $scope.fillCountryList = function () {
            var raw =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Countries));
            $scope.CountryList = raw["Data"];
        }
        $scope.fillCountryList();
    });
</script>
```